How can I receive a Google Maps notification when people share their location with me?
When someone is sharing their location using Google Maps with me, normally, I should receive a push notification.
But for years now, I don't receive any notification anymore, no matter the phone (tried with several ones) or Android or Google Maps versions.
I have noticed in the Google Maps Notifications settings that I'm missing some entries as showed below on my Google Pixel 6a:



Then in "Location and profile", here are the entries:



When switching to another Google account, I have the missing entries for sharing notifications:



It sounds like it's related to my personal Google account, but I've never figured out what or how I can re-enable these notifications back.

I'm living in France.
I've checked that I'm recognized as an adult (> 18 years old) at https://myaccount.google.com/age-verification
I'm the Family manager on Google Family.

Any clue?
Originally posted on: https://support.google.com/maps/thread/76333024

Possible dupe: Mobile Google Maps' setting for receiving location share notifications, but the answer might not be applicable since the menu itself is not visible.

There's also Google Maps Help - Get Location Sharing notifications mentioning "Location Sharing notifications aren't available for certain accounts and sharing via links.", but it's unclear what "certain accounts" means.

I note the "Get Location Sharing notifications" doc is about setting up notifications "to know when they arrive at or leave a specific location", not a notification that a new person has shared their location with you.  (It looks like "for certain accounts" means "The sharer is under 13 (or the applicable age in their country).")

Thanks for your replies.
Indeed, there are 2 different features: Google Maps notifications upon departure or arrival of a contact, and when someone is sharing their real-time location with you.
This page is the closest to the real-time location sharing I'm asking in my question: Share your real-time location with others.
